# OnePlus One Adb Connection - Offline

Tags: android, debugging, adb, driver, oneplusone

I'm trying to debug an app on my OnePlus One, but I'm not able to connect the phone to my laptop, since I get an "adb devices" offline status.

[image]

Here's my configuration:

- **OPO**: Android 6.0.1, Debug Mode activated (PTP)
- **Laptop**: Windows 10 64bit

I've followed a lot of guides/discussions/threads and tried a bunch of different driver (Samsung Universal Driver, ADB Driver [v1.4.3 *and* 1.3], Google USB Driver, 15 second adb/fastboot installer...) but none worked.

I also tried and manually force-update the driver in the Device Manager but I can't get anything but what you can see in this image:

[image]

Any thought about this issue?

Comment: Remove device from USB and connect it again with power supply ON on the laptop.

Comment: Power supply is already ON. It has always been, throughout all my attempts.